# How to identify manually added routes

Tags: windows, routing

I have added a bunch of routes manually which are persistent ( a while ago). Now how do I find which of these are auto and which are manual.

OS: Windows 7

Edit1:

The routes I mentioned, are in windows, since I have multiple interfaces.

I used the "route add" command to add the routes.

Comment: @Mate : I have updated the question.

Comment: I've answered, if your happy to upload a screenshot of the result of your "route print" I would be happy to help pick out your static routes.

Answer (score 1):

Open up cmd and type "route print" You should get the screen below[image: route print]

Your static routes should have a low metric (They will be used first in the event that two routes overlap.)
Higher metric numbers should be automatic. The exception is the default 0.0.0.0 route which will be 35.

More info here:[Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/)

Answer (score 0):

What @Lister said. All static routes you added should have a metric of (metric of default route) + 1.

@mods: this should be a comment to but I've not enough reputation yet.